# Массив возвращает корневой путь сайта

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Всем привет. 
Есть функция

```
public function actionUploadAsync($attribute)
    {
         $response=[
            'files'=>[]
        ];
        print_r($response);

    }
```

Она грузиться с помощью Ajax. Тут переменная $response пустая, но вот что выдает консоль

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
        )

)
<!--/var/www/www-root/data/www/chiga.kz/public-->
```

Из за того что он выдает мне корневой путь, у меня ругается ajax скрипт что есть символ < . Не понимаю, откуда берется этот путь, где копать? и второй вариант, может как то получиться что бы вырезать его? просто он находиться грубо говоря вне массива

Comment: путь выводит не "массив", а какой-то другой код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш ajax-запрос ожидает в ответе json-объект, в аы возвращаете незнамо что.

Попробуйте так:

```php
public function actionUploadAsync($attribute)
{
    $response=[
        'files'=>[]
    ];
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: Сделал так, все ровно возвращает {"files":[]}<!--/var/www/www-root/data/www/chiga.kz/public-->  Путь <!--/var/www/www-root/data/www/chiga.kz/public--> почему то возвращает, непонятно

Comment: Как быстрое решение, можно добавить после `echo json_encode($response);` `die;`, но это путь плохого бойца. Нужно разобраться, откуда появляется этот комментарий. Проект на каком-то фреймворке или самописный?

Comment: фреймворк Yii первой версии. Сам уже с ума схожу. Скачал весь дистрибутив, сделал поиск по файлам, нету ниодного совпадения. Может хостинг шалит?

Comment: Есть желание поковыряться за деньги конечно)

Comment: хостинг вряд ли шалит. Посмотрите внимательно `index.php`, потом `beforeAction` / `afterAction` методы контроллера и его родительских классов.

Comment: Бро, капец, в Index была эта проблема, просто жесть. Пиши ЯД, закину подгончик

Comment: Спасибо! не стоит :)